# How to hook DNS query request in windows?

Tags: windows, dns, hook

I want to hook DNS query request in windows, I use IAThook to hook "gethostbyname","getaddrinfo","GetAddrInfoW", "GetAddrInfoExA","GetAddrInfoExW","WSAAsyncGetHostByName", but seems most app didn't link the ws2_32.dll statically at all. So I also hook "GetProcAddress" in kernel32.dll, but them also don't use "gethostbyname"...at all(but the DNS query request actually be sent). I test this with MsEdge explorer and many other apps. I do this in LSP.
Do these apps not usr such as "gethostbyname" function to send a DNS request? How can I do?
Can somebody give me some help?

my code like this:

```
long hookGetProcAddress()
{
    long ret = 0;
    FUNCBEGINLOG
    if (g_hHook_GetProcAddressFunc != NULL)
    {
        dbgprint("%s hookGetProcAddress already hooked!", moduleBaseName);
        return ret;
    }

    ret = IATHook(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), "kernel32.dll", "GetProcAddress", 
          LSPGetProcAddress, &g_hHook_GetProcAddressFunc);
    dbgprint("%s hookGetProcAddress func ret %d!", moduleBaseName, ret);

    FUNCFINISHLOG
    return ret;
}

long hookgethostbyname()
{
    long ret = 0;
    FUNCBEGINLOG
    if (g_hHook_gethostbynameFunc != NULL)
    {
        dbgprint("%s hookgethostbyname already hooked!", moduleBaseName);
        return ret;
    }

   ret = IATHook(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), "Ws2_32.dll", "gethostbyname", 
       LSPgethostbyname, 
    &g_hHook_gethostbynameFunc);
   dbgprint("%s hookgethostbyname func ret %d!", moduleBaseName, ret);

   FUNCFINISHLOG
   return ret;
}

long hookgetaddrinfo()
{
    long ret = 0;
    FUNCBEGINLOG
    if (g_hHook_getaddrinfoFunc != NULL)
    {
        dbgprint("%s hookgetaddrinfo already hooked!", moduleBaseName);
        return ret;
    }

    ret = IATHook(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), "Ws2_32.dll", "getaddrinfo", LSPgetaddrinfo, &g_hHook_getaddrinfoFunc);
    dbgprint("%s hookgetaddrinfo func ret %d!", moduleBaseName, ret);

    FUNCFINISHLOG
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how the Liskov substitution principle applies here. Removed the tag.

Comment: Browsers now use DNS over HTTPS, depending on which, which version and which configuration. If that happens, you won't be able to intercept anything